# How to display high resolution images in iOS4 using UIImageView

Tags: ios4

I wanted to know how should I use high res images in iOS4 sdk using UIImaageView.

```
blackBox = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alert_bg.png"]];
blackBox.frame = CGRectMake(98.0f, 310.0f, 573.0f, 177.0f);
```

When I use this code I get strange results... the image does not get the correct size. It is looking very big on iPhone 4 screen.

Should I use 326 ppi images?

I have read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html this but I am very confuse.

Thanks

Saurabh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing to understand about supporting the Retina Display is that, in your code, **the screen is always 320x480**. You don't need to double the resolution of anything but your image resources themselves. In this case, you just need to put two resources in your app bundle: an `alert_bg.png` that fits on a 320x480 screen—in this case, I'd guess that'd be 286x88—and an `alert_bg@2x.png`, exactly double the size of the other, that fits on a 640x960 one. If you ask UIKit for `[UIImage imageNamed:@"alert_bg"]`, it'll automatically pick the correct-resolution resource for the current screen.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a 480x320 pixels image for the 3G, 3GS and original iPhone, named "alert_bg.png" and another 960x640 px one, named "alert_bg@2x.png" for the iPhone 4.

The "@2x" in the name is automatically added by iOS and loads the image automatically if it finds it, instead of the standard resolution one.