# UIImageView with setImage: Image is not Visible on Debugger Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm trying to show an image with following method:

```
[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
```

And it's working just fine with the iPhone simulator. However, when I debug on the device, the image is not visible.

Clearly it's about resolution because the resolution of my image is much more higher than UIImageView's(and it has to be...) and also when I use an image with same resolution of UIImageView, it's working fine on device, too.

I tried what said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644912/iphone-uiimageview-setimage-leaks) but it didn't solve my problem.

What do you suggest to make UIImageView work with larger images than its frame?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your image is named "myImage.png" the simulator isn't case sensitive and the device is.

Comment: I am, also my images are numeric named like 1213.png etc.

Answer (score 0):

If image resolution is your problem, try the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760494/how-to-display-high-resolution-images-in-ios4-using-uiimageview). Else, try the sample [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/PhotoScroller.zip) in Apple's Reference Library. It provides a way to display big images in chunks (tiles). That should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
myImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,200,300)];
[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
[self.view addSubView:myImageView];
```

It will work.

Comment: The UIImageView is an IB element but I tried your code anyway, it didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have anotherView ? and add SubView on self.view

Comment: It's all about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449256/download-and-save-image-to-root#comment4859514_4449256 "imageNamed: works only with images you deployed with your app-package. But you can't write to this package - you have to save your image to your app documents folder." I'm downloading images... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest issue that can occur sometimes. It is because of the image name case sensitivity required in the device while the simulator ignore the case sensitivity for the image name.

So, make sure your image name in the bungle is exactly the same what you are specified here. Not even on capital or small letter difference. Just check the image name - "myImage.png"

Please let me know if you still have any problem in the UIImageView image display.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my comment under the question, I'm using numeric file names so that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm downloading images to show in runtime, I'm getting the application main bundle path with this code below:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath]];
NSArray *parts = [path componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *pathToSave = [path substringToIndex:([path length] - [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [parts objectAtIndex:[parts count]-1]] length])];
```

And I save images with this code:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [imageURLs objectAtIndex:0]];
NSString *filename = [url lastPathComponent];
NSData *thedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSString *localFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i%@", pathToSave, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [element child:@"id"]] intValue], filename];
[thedata writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
```

When I manually download an image and add to project, `[UIImageView setImage:]` did work this time. So I realized that there's something wrong with saving images from URL.

The reason I didn't think this should be the problem is that it's working just fine with the iOS simulator.

I'll take a look at that issue, however since my application name contains special characters like "İ" (Turkish) I think that might be the reason, the application might not be able to save to correct path.